# Why does RAM fragmentation degrade performance if data can be accessed randomly?

Tags: ram, fragmentation

From what I've read, fragmentation is a problem because only contiguous blocks of memory can be allocated. Why is this? Since data in RAM can be accessed in any order, can't non-contiguous blocks of memory be read just as fast? I've been thinking about this because I read that fragmentation of SSDs isn't a problem since they're random access.

Comment: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf‎

Comment: You can't allocate a single array in two non-contiguous chunks of memory.  Also, CPU cache coherency.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks I'll be learning more about cache coherency soon. I've been learning about kernels though, and it seems like linked list are a commonly used data structure. Is it because they don't need to be stored contiguously?